# UICollectionView crashes as layout param is "nil".. but it's not - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am building a UICollectionView with a custom collectionCell. But I get the error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'`

But as you can see from the code, I am very explicitly creating the layout and passing it as a param when initializing the collection view.

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sentMngr.retrieveSent()
    let flow = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    flow.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
    flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical

    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: flow)
    self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView!.delegate = self
    self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

The custom cell code:

```
import UIKit

class CollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var imageView: UIImageView!
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height*2/3))
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    self.addSubview(imageView)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild project? (Cmd+Shift+K)

Comment: Your view controller inherits from `UICollectionViewController` so you shouldn't need to initialize a new collection view & assign it to `self.collectionView`. Try deleting that line & see what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. Which line? I need to build a CollectionView to show..

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your code as:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class ProfileViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sentMngr.retrieveSent()

    self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Register cell classes
self.collectionView!.registerClass(CollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
   self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

I faced the same problem the app crashed as soon as it launches. Worked fine when initialized like below

`var alarmCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())`

I am using autoLayout so used CGRect.zero in frame